# Cronjob putty doesn't go on

Tags: cron, putty

I recorded a cronjob :

```
*/5 * * * * cd /home/titi/sync-expedition-teliae-magento && /usr/local/bin/docker-compose exec php-apache sh -c "bin/console app:sync-shipment"
```

Unfortunately it doesn't go on... I don't know why.
Do you have any explanation?

It works well when I do it manually with putty.

[image: Screenshot of putty crontab]

Comment: Your title and question are contradictory. are you Unable to run this job with cron? Or is this job is running using cron and won't stop? Please edit your question and try to explain better what the problem is.

Comment: You say both "go off" and "go on"... which is it? Do you mean the cronjob doesn't start?

Comment: Why do it like this? create a script... put these lines in a script and add a log file 1 very big difference: from cron you run it as root. from commandline as a user. Maybe Apache does not like to be run as root.

Comment: Ty. Sorry it’s cron dont start.

Comment: Rinzwind. I make this crontab with root user.